# How to format a disk to NTFS using Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, disk-format, ntfs

I am looking for a simple GUI based way to format drives to NTFS (Windows) on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OS X can default read NTFS disks, but not write to them.

Possible solutions/options:

[**NTFS for Mac OS X**](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/index.html) *(10 Days Trial)*: I use this one, and it does the job very well. When the driver is installed, you format your NTFS disks with `Disk Utility` where you select `Windows NT Filesystem` as the format.

[**Tuxera NTFS for Mac**](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) *(15 Days Trial)*: I haven't tried this one, but it should also do the job.

Comment: Tuxera works great (http://img42.com/nCyA1+)

Comment: I needed to perform an offline system update for Xbox One S but I only have Macs.  Installed the Paragon NTFS for Mac using 10 day trial. That allowed me to format a USB drive as NTFS with full read-write access and then write the system update files to the USB drive. Offline Xbox update worked like a charm via USB stick.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to have `ntfs-3g` driver and `FUSE` for macOS which extends the file handling capabilities of the OS. Both these things are open source.

I am not explaining the downloading and installation instructions here because the link below has explained each and everything on how to make NTFS drive work with macOS. This worked successfully on my macOS Sierra.

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G

Answer (score 4):

You can now use [Fuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/). It's very useful and easy to be installed.
Moreover, it's **free**.

Comment: Their wiki says they use `ntfs-3g` for NTFS. Apparently write performance is poor.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, unfortunately Fuse still requires a `ntfs-3g` driver which is not free.

Comment: Fuse GUI is just an about box

Comment: I installed Fuse but it seems pretty useless...

Answer (score 1):

There is nice article [How to Write to NTFS Drives on a Mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/236055/how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-on-a-mac/)

Seagate offer [Paragon Driver for Mac OS](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/) or you can buy [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) for

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.